# Unable to feed JSONL data to AutoML NLP - Entity Extraction

Tags: google-cloud-automl, automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

So, I'm trying to implement Entity Extraction for AutoML and I'm a complete beginner. My CSV file upload is successful but my JSONL isn't being parsed correctly. Where am I going wrong? The starting line of the file contains all the training data. I haven't annotated it yet as I intend to do so on the UI. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I used Pandas to convert it to JSONL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `textContent` key instead of `text_snippet`. Check out the [AI Platform docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/datasets/prepare-text#entity-extraction) versus the [Cloud Natural Language docs](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#expandable-2)

I recently had this issue because I was trying to use AI Platform's Natural Language with the format defined for Cloud Natural Language AutoML. I did not initially realize these were separate products and had different schemas for importing data.

Try this JSONL schema to see if it works.

```
{
    "textSegmentAnnotations": [
      {
        "startOffset":number,
        "endOffset":number,
        "displayName": "label"
      },
      ...
    ],
    "textContent": "inline_text"|"textGcsUri": "gcs_uri_to_file",
    "dataItemResourceLabels": {
      "aiplatform.googleapis.com/ml_use": "training|test|validation"
    }
}
```